# Why isn't this a syntax error in SAS?

Tags: sas

I noticed that it's possible to define character variables like this:

```
data _null_;
myvar = ('a'); /*What are these brackets doing?*/
put _all_;
run;
```

Much to my surprise, this doesn't generate any errors. Does this syntax serve any particular purpose, or is it just equivalent to

```
data _null_;
myvar = 'a';
put _all_;
run;
```

in all respects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`('a')` is an expression that evaluates to the string `'a'`, just like `(1 + 2)` evaluates to `3`.

`myvar = ('a');` is equivalent to `myvar = 'a';`, just like
`myvar = (1 + 2);` is equivalent to `myvar = 3;`.

Comment: Can you think of any situation which would require the use of this syntax when creating a character variable?

Comment: Sometimes it's used to make logical expressions clearer, for instance `varA = (myvar = 'a');` rather than `varA = myvar = 'a';`.